# nofollow on local images improving SERP?

Tags: seo, images, links, search-results, nofollow

I have links to images on my website (fined with lightbox),

when I extend the links with `rel="lightbox nofollow"` would this increase the link juice value of the other links? I don't need all of the images indexed, a few of em.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>More PageRank would flow through the links that don't contain the `nofollow` link relationship yes.</strike>

It is not advisable to `nofollow` links for the benefit of manipulating PageRank though (PageRank sculpting) - for content that you do not wish to be indexed or crawled, it should contain the meta `NOINDEX` tag (pages) or be disallowed in the `robots.txt` (files and directories).

As pointed out in the comments, by nofollowing internal links on your website, this no longer causes more PageRank to flow via the followable links.

This illustration from Moz demonstrates how PageRank flows pretty well:-

[image: Moz: PageRank flow]

And to cite a snippet from [this article](http://moz.com/blog/google-says-yes-you-can-still-sculpt-pagerank-no-you-cant-do-it-with-nofollow):-

> So what happens when you have a page with “ten PageRank points” and
>   ten outgoing links, and five of those links are nofollowed? Let’s
>   leave aside the decay factor to focus on the core part of the
>   question. Originally, the five links without nofollow would have
>   flowed two points of PageRank each (in essence, the nofollowed links
>   didn’t count toward the denominator when dividing PageRank by the
>   outdegree of the page). **More than a year ago, Google changed how the
>   PageRank flows so that the five links without nofollow would flow one
>   point of PageRank each.**

Thanks to @Binarysurf for the clarification of this.

Comment: The first part of your statement is not correct. Nofollowed links will count when dividing pagerank into the total links on the page, but because they are nofollowed that pagerank will be discarded, it will be lost. Then, using nofollow, will not give more pagerank to other links.

Comment: Can you cite an official source (such as Google) where they have declared that? I'm not in any way saying I don't believe you, I know my answer used to be the case but seeing as I have never chased PageRank or batted one eyelid at it, there is a possibility I may have this wrong.

Comment: I apologize, I didn't include any reference:


Matt Cutts, from Google Webmasters channel
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4SAPUx4Beh8


Seo Moz http://moz.com/blog/google-says-yes-you-can-still-sculpt-pagerank-no-you-cant-do-it-with-nofollow


http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/7210/should-i-add-rel-nofollow-to-menu-links


http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2298312/Matt-Cutts-You-Dont-Have-to-Nofollow-Internal-Links

Comment: Thank you for this. I've corrected my answer based on your cited source from Moz.

Answer (score 1):

Using `nofollow` will not improve your SERP's at all, neither will share more pagerank to other links inside a page. So, you better don't do it, it will hurt your site.

It's not recommended to use `nofollow` on internal links because it drops (Matt Cutts said "[evaporates](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4SAPUx4Beh8)") pagerank. Links `nofollow`ed are taken into account when calculating pagerank distribution between all links inside a page, then, their pagerank part is dropped.

Why blocking your images? It's better if all of your content (pages, images, video, etc.) are indexed, every single item might be another door for letting visitors get into your site.